# PHP filter_input_array() not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery AJAX to send an array to a PHP script, my jQuery code is as following :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false
});
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    row_ids : row_ids//This is the array sent
  },
  url: "CRUD.php",
  success: function (response) {
   alert(response);
  },
  error: function () {
   alert("Server side error, try later!"); 
  }                      
});
```

The PHP code that gets the array is as following :

```
<?php
//Working code :
$ids = $_POST['row_ids'];
print_r($ids);

//Not working code :
$ids = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, 'row_ids');
print_r($ids);
?>
```

for a simple variable sent via AJAX to PHP the `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'variable_passed');`
is working fine for me.

Can someone tell me why it is not working for filter_input_array?

Thanks.

Comment: Second argument for `filter_input_array` is ether an array or a integer constant. Read more in a manual

Answer (score 0):

You are using this function wrong. Please read how to use this function in php documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php

The second argument MUST be array with definitions to validate

Example usage:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
/* data actually came from POST
$_POST = array(
        'product_id'    => 'libgd<script>',
        'component'     => '10',
        'versions'      => '2.0.33',
        'testscalar'    => array('2', '23', '10', '12'),
        'testarray'     => '2',
);
*/

$args = array(
        'product_id'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED,
        'component'    => array(
                    'filter'    => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                    'flags'     => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY, 
                    'options'   => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 10)
        ),
        'versions'     => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED,
        'doesnotexist' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        'testscalar'   => array(
                        'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                        'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
        ),
        'testarray'    => array(
                        'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                        'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,
                       )

    );

    $myinputs = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);

    var_dump($myinputs);
    echo "\n";
?>
```

Comment: if I'm using it the wrong way why this is working for me :filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name_of_the_variable_sent_from_ajax'); if I do a var dump I get the correct value sent when it is a simple var not an array

Comment: Look closer you are talking for a completely different function : filter_input. In the post you are taliking about filter_input_array. Please ready documentation for both functions and what they do.